# Android VerifyError: Rejecting class android.widget.NumberPicker because it failed compile-time verification

Tags: java, android

I've got an error log, but still can't figure out what's wrong. All I can provide is this log, and want to see is there any suggestion or ideas to help?

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker-android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(633)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(55)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(682)
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class android.widget.NumberPicker because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'android.widget.NumberPicker' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)-java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(-2)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(288)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(607)
```

Comment: Can u post your code?

Comment: Search for "because it failed compile-time verification"